# mySQL error 1227 while migrating using workbench for tables with more than one foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, data-migration

So I am trying migrate a mySQL DB using mySQL workbecnh.
I am currently able to successfully connect to

1. The source I am getting the data and schema from
2. The Target I am moving the data to

The migration succeed for

1. Normal Table with no foreign key
2. Table with one foreign key

And it fails for

1. Tables with two foreign keys referencing two tables
2. A view that is constructed based on two tables

The exact issue was

```
Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.
SQL Error: 1227
```

Noting that the user I am using to connect does have all the privileges.

I created it myself and assigned it to the DB using another user. And Btw I tried to use both users to connect and I got the exact same result

Comment: share your user privileges you can share results of following command: "show grants for 'my_user'@'%';" change % with ip if you are using rights ip wise.

Comment: @ZafarMalik where to run this command ?

Comment: you can run in mysqlwork bench query browser or after connecting mysql from console as you wish.

Comment: @ZafarMalik so I ran the command show grants for 'my_user'@'%';

[RESULT WAS]
Access denied for user 'login_user'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'.  

[NOTE THAT]
login_user is the user I use to login to my cpanel

Comment: Actually your issue is related with privileges here as well during data migration...try with any admin user.

Comment: @ZafarMalik I am actually trying the user "login_user" who is the admin and the username I am using to access

Comment: do you have root user privilegs.